# Showing a combined Top 10

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a combined top 10 in powerBI.

I have a 'process name' then for each process, I would like powerBI to find the top 10 of that process for 'cost', then the top 10 for 'count A' then top 10 for 'count B'.

The same process could be in the top 10 for cost, count A and count B. This also means there could be more than 10 of 'process name' showing because I would like it to show the top10 for 'cost','count A' and 'count B'.

I could achieve this in excel by using sumif's, countif's and then manually filtering for top10 on each category then remove duplicates and use for my graph.

I don't know if this is possible in powerbi, could somebody provide some guidance?

Thanks

I've tried ranking by top 10 but I can only add one value in powerbi. I've also thought of seeing if there is a formula that will check for top 10 of each and then return a result, then I could create a measure for combined top 10 but I'm not that experienced yet to know if it will work

Comment: 3 measures (one for each 10-top) and another measure to see if any of the 10-tops are true.  Working through understanding these would help a ton - https://www.daxpatterns.com/patterns/

Comment: Thanks I will try work through those! Do you know which measures I could use? I've tried rankx but it's given the same rank for similar values, so wondered if there was a another measure I could use

Comment: Why is that a problem? How and why would you break a tie between two elements that both score the same rank?

Comment: It's a problem because it doesn't look like it's ranking correctly. If I do a count on the number of processes in the data set, the count is the same as the ranking and this shouldn't be the case if the ranking is based off values?

Comment: Can you show me the sample? I'm having a hard time picturing your issue.